# Peak detection in an audio signal

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, fft

I need to find the maximum peak of an audio signal using matlab. I have got the input using `wavread` command and converted the signal into frequency domain using FFT. After finding the magnitude of it, I need to store the peak value for further calculation. How can I do this?

Comment: There is the `findpeaks` function in the signal processing toolbox.

Comment: I used it, but it tells me an error. For example, if I stored the magnitude in a variable IN_MAG, and created another variable PEAK = findpeaks(IN_MAG), it tells error like this. ??? Error using ==> findpeaks
Expected X to be a vector.

Error in ==> findpeaks at 42
validateattributes(X,{'numeric'},{'nonempty','real','vector'},...

Comment: You may check the dimension of IN_MAG. The input "requires a row or column vector with real-valued elements with a minimum length of three"

Comment: @Gogui please post some code of how do you store you magnitude and a plot of it. It all depends of how many peaks and so on.

Comment: Kumar and Pal have a good ALE notch filter that very efficient at finding the center frequency.

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=414768

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your `IN_MAG` is not a real vector, meaning you are storing both real and imaginary part of your FFT. I would advice you to read the `doc fft` of matlab documentation so you can create a proper vector.

In case you can complete this, if you want a unique peak, the maximum, just use the function `max`. In case not you can personalize what you what to find,

Let's say finding the first 3 peaks with minimum height of 0.5 and with a distance of 10 points from each other,

```
[pks, locs] = findpeaks(IN_MAG, 'NPEAKS', 3, 'MINPEAKHEIGHT', 0.5, 'MINPEAKDISTANCE', 10);
```

Then `pks` is your `y` and `locs` is your `x` coordenate from your peaks.

EDIT:

As to FFT,

Let's say `sig` is your signal,

```
t = linspace(0,L/Fs,L); % Fs is the sampling rate in Hz and L the signal length

NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L);
f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);

fft_sig = fft(sig, NFFT)/L;

magnitude_sig = = 2*abs(fft_sig(1:NFFT/2+1));
```

this is your correct fft magnitude signal.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will see to that. And this is my code.               in = wavread('C:\Users\Gogul\Desktop\C note mono.wav');
IN=fft(in);
IN_MAG=abs(IN);
plot(IN_MAG);
title('Magnitude of Audio sample');
SRATE = 44100;
LEN = length(IN_MAG);
FREQ = (SRATE*PEAK)/LEN;
% PEAK is the maximum peak in the audio sample.

Comment: Thanks a ton. This is for a project on audio processing. This fft conversion is to detect the frequency of a guitar sound, say C note. If I could find the maximum peak of it, and multiply that x axis value with sampling rate, and divide it with the length of the audio signal, I could find the exact frequency of the input signal. Can you get what am upto?

Comment: @Gogui The `x` axis of the magnitude of the FFT signal is actually already in `Hz`.